# include php file in page using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I include php link in page using Javascript

Using only Javascript

I had a code but forgotten it

ex

This in php

```
 <? php
 file_get_contents('www.xxxxxxxxx.com/icn.php); 
  ?>
```

I want in Javascript

Comment: ajax is what you want

Comment: you need to use ajax. have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: You can use php to construct a javascript string that contains the file. If you've used `file_get_contents` put it in your html file. `echo '<script type="text/javascript">var doc = "'$doc_content'"</script>'`. Something like this.

Comment: I want to use Ajax only without php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are including an external domain in the precess (not using a relative path), the request will probably be cancelled due to the same origin policy browser implements to avoid cross-site forgery. In that case, you may want to have a PHP file on your website that just proxies your request to the actual site you want to load and use AJAX to your local PHP script.

```
Your Javascript <> PHP script on the same domain <> www.xxxxxxxxx.com/icn.php
```

If www.xxxxxxxxx.com happens to be your own website, you can just do a regular AJAX call to "icn.php". To do AJAX calls, you may want to read about [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or use a library that does the job for you, like [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

If you really absolutely need to load data from an external domain purely on client side, you can either use hacks like [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) or an invisible `<iframe>`, listen to its onload event and get its content. But be careful, these usually requires the external site to be compatible with these kind of requests (not a big deal if you manage both ends).

Answer (score -2):

> fun.php
>
> < ?php
>
> echo 'hello World';
>
> ?>
>
> function foo() {
>
> var i = < ?php include('fun.php');?>
>
> console.log( i );
>
> }

Comment: I want to use Ajax only without php